# Django apache mod_wsgi permission denied

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, chmod

I have installed apache and mod_wsgi, and all the web pages are retrieved and displayed, but with NO static files loaded such as css, when I try to access a static file (e.g:http://localhost/static/css/base.css) it says that I don't have permission to access the file, same goes to media files. So basically the webpage returned is just pure HTML.

I have followed the steps in the presentation slides http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/detail?name=mod_wsgi-pycon-sydney-2010.pdf and made the directories accessible to others via `chmod o+rx /home/loai/workspace/Faculty`
, my  httpd.conf part is :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/loai/workspace/Faculty

Alias /media/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/media
Alias /static/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/static

<Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

a strange thing is that when I remove the "Files"  directive so it becomes:

```
<Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

instead of 

<Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

then trying to access any static or media file raises (not found) instead of permission denied ! but still the pure-html page is loaded !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..if it does try adding the configuration for media directory. Make sure to recursively set read permission on the static folder

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/

    Alias /static/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/static/

    <Directory /home/loai/workspace/Faculty>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory> 
    <Location "/static/">
        SetHandler None
    </Location>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/wsgi.py
    </VirtualHost>
```

Update:

I would suggest copying your static folder outside the faculty application. And I have changed the path in the configuration file.

Comment: still gives the same errors,
regarding the configuration thing, all sub directories have the permission of drwxr-xr-x, resulting from applying chmod o+rx on the root directory. cmod -R gave no difference

Comment: Are you able to get the files from django's development server?

Comment: yes, and everything works like a charm on the development server

Comment: Please copy your static folder outside the faculty application folder and pasting it inside faculty project folder and change the path accordingly in the config file and try again.

Comment: actually I already used collectstatic, which did the copying thing, but and the apache path is pointing at the project folder.

Comment: man I didn't notice that you mentioned the trailing slash stuff, it works now, thanks a million :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
Alias /media/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/media
Alias /static/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/static
```

use:

```
Alias /media/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/media/
Alias /static/ /home/loai/workspace/Faculty/Faculty/static/
```

If you have trailing slash on mount point, you need to have trailing slash on directory. If you don't have them matching, may not work.

Comment: Straight hero comment right here.  Thanks, that fixed my issue while following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/